# No `package.json` file found. Make sure you are running the command in a Node.js project

Tags: angularjs

I am building a AngularJS file with typescript and installed tsd for typedefinitions globally. When I try to run the following command on the root of my project folder I am getting an error

I am new Angular JS using version 1.7. I am not sure if Package.json is needed for AngularJS project

Command

tsd install angular --resolve --save

Error
No `package.json` file found. Make sure you are running the command in a Node.js project.

Answer (score 1):

package.json is required for node projects to specify metadata about project and include some important commands that may be required for the project build. First you have to install node from official website. You can google for the step by step installation. Once installed, goto your project directory and run this command. Make sure to perform "npm init" before you run the desired angular command.
Note: Ensure, node is accessible through cli

tsd is deprecated use @types node modules

```js
npm i @types/angular --save
```

Comment: Please bear in mind that it is AngularJS application. I added a blank package.json at the root and also ran npm init. it added some json code n the package.json. when i i run the tsd command tsd install angular --resolve --save, it throws an error type definition index.d.ts does not exist